# Python class error using pycharm community

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Using pycharm community software,  i created this code

```
Class calculator :
          def addition (x, y) 
                 added = x+y
                  Print (added) 
Calculator1 = calculator()
Calculator.addition(3,5)
```

I get this error

```
calculator.addition(3,5)
TypeError: substration() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall try by adding the keyword `self` in the `addition` method like below

```
class calculator:
    def addition (self, x, y):
        added = x+y
        print (added)

Calculator = calculator()
Calculator.addition(3,5)
```